# Combine two nodes into one, taking value from one and name from other node

Tags: xslt

I would want to transform the nodes like:

```
<Element>
      <Type>Type1</Type>
      <Quantity>q1</Quantity>
</Element>
```

(Type node value comes from an enum) into:

```
<Element>
  <Type1>q1</Type1>
</Element>
```

only in the case that both nodes exist. Otherwise, if node `<Quantity>` does not exist, but node `<LastDate>` exists instead, then this node:

```
<Element>
  <Type>Date</Type>
  <LastDate>date string</LastDate>
</Element>
```

becomes:

```
<Element>
  <Date>date string</Date>
</Element>
```

So the name of the new node is always taken from the value of `<Type>` node, but its value may come from different children nodes (when they exist) of the parent `<Element>` node. The children nodes that contain the value get deleted in the final output, along with the `<Type>` node.

I have no problem doing this in Linq to XML C# code. However, as this kind of transformation can apply to several different nodes, the command line input to my program, specifying which nodes are affected and how, becomes complicated.

In contrast xslt has the added value of being self-documenting for simple transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<xsl:element>` to create an element out of thin air.

So you need something like (not tested for typos):

```
  <xsl:template match="Element">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="{Type}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="(Quantity|LastDate)/node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

This code copies the `<Element>` element and then creates the child element out of thin air using the name of the content of the child element `<Type>`.

The use of brace brackets is an attribute value template, the XPath address within which is evaluated like an `<xsl:value-of>` instruction.

Comment: Works as expected and will accept it as an answer. I just need a bit of extra help, regarding the detail that I haven't mentioned in the OP. The Element node has other nodes that should be preserved as such.

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Just needed to add an extra copy statement:
`<xsl:copy-of select="(Other)"/>` but would like to know if it is possible to copy all other children nodes of Element without enumerating them all explicitly.

Comment: In XSLT 1 `<xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::Type|self::Quantity|self::LastDate)]"/>` will copy all children except those children where the given elements are found along the self:: axis (that is, that they are one of the given elements).  In XSLT 2 this is much easier:  `<xsl:copy select="* except ( Type | Quantity | LastDate )"/>`